# Get wine to honor system fontconfig settings (subpixel antialiasing, slight hinting)

Tags: wine, fontconfig

A freshly compiled Wine-1.7.51 works almost fine, but it does not honor the system's (Gnome's) fontconfig settings. Specifically, it ignores subpixel rendering (using greyscale antialiasing if the system uses greyscale or RGB, and no antialiasing otherwise). It also ignores the hinting setting (None, Slight, Medium, Full). I don't know which it defaults to, but it always looks the same.

Wine is built using the system fontconfig / freetype, which works fine, and supports RGB subpixel antialiasing and slight hinting (which is what I want). This is not one of the old bytecode interpreter or lcd filter issues with freetype, my system freetype is fine for me. I also tried multiple fonts; I know wine might override the settings for certain default fonts.

I remember there was "one wierd trick" to get wine to use the right settings, but I forgot what it was (it was probably either a small source code change, or a custom fontconfig XML file that got loaded via environment variable). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

2021 Update:

- Wine's `dlls/gdi32/freetype.c` currently does try to get a default antialias setting in `default_aa_flags`. It... should do the antialias automatically now.
- I have no idea how the `is_hinting_enabled()` function is used. Sorry.

---

As far as I know there's no way to get wine to honor `fontconfig` antialias settings.

- To get RGB antialiasing, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/29552 (winetricks). It changes a registry value that's managed independent of fc.
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134977 Gives font linking (aliasing) in fontconfig, but has nothing to do with anti-alias. It is an XML though.

---

I think wine honors nothing from fontconfig but those font name links by default. The infinality guys made one for wine to honor those rendering things, during some wine-1.1 ages. Like most other exciting wine patches, it was never merged.

I thought I saw that patch somewhere, but I can't find it yet. As a fallback suggestion, tell us what your distro is so I can see what patches they added to wine.

P.S.: For wine with exciting stuff, try wine-staging.